# Early reference to row of a csv file imported as list break my read dataset?

Tags: python, list, indexing, jupyter, square-bracket

I am opening, reading and storing into a list data structure the content of a csv file (https://www.kaggle.com/ramamet4/app-store-apple-data-set-10k-apps).
I tried to store header and rest of the dataset in two separate variables trying to avoid the cumbersome foo = list(bar) and instead did something like foo = list(bar)[0]. This works fine till I try to do the same with the rest of the dataset or just another row. Using slice don't give any error but still, I get an empty variable, using foo=list(bar)[1] give an 'Index out of range' exception. If I do reference [1] before [0] I am getting no complaints about the index, I don't get why that happend.

Using Jupyter Notebook,

```
`from csv import reader
     oDs1 = open('AppleStore.csv')
     oDs2 = open('googleplaystore.csv')
     rDs1 = reader(oDs1)
     rDs2 = reader(oDs2)
     header = list(rDs1)[0] #everything is fine here, no matter which index 
     #number I choose
     print(*header)
     restofDataSet = list(rDs1)[1:3] #short slice for test, no error but 
     #variable is empty
     print(*restofDataSet)
     firstRow= list(rDs1)[1] #python raise error`
```

I would expect to have my header and rest of dataset (or at least another test row) variables assigned but I get empty dataset on the slice method and the following error while I reference another index after the first ([0]):

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-16-0baa98682a7a> in <module>()
      8 restofDataSet = list(rDs1)[1:3]
      9 print(*restofDataSet)
---> 10 firstRow= list(rDs1)[1]
     11 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using pandas to read the csv?

Comment: I am following the DataQuest course "Python for Data Science Fundamentals" and therefore using just the tools they provide, I guess panda is going to be explained in following courses but that is just something that has to do with the language syntax as I would do the same in Powershell

Comment: `reader(oDs1)` might be a generator meaning the first time you call `list(rDs1)` you exhaust the generator so the second time you call it, it might return `None`. Try remove the line `restofDataSet = list(rDs1)[1:3]` and see if your error goes away.

Comment: I'll check what's a generator for future knowledge but it doesn't seem to be the problem:
`IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f60102c65ed2> in <module>()
      6 header = list(rDs1)[0]
      7 print(*header)
----> 8 firstRow= list(rDs1)[1]
      9 

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That's because you are already emptying out the generator here `header = list(rDs1)[0]`. Try this instead `rDs1 = list(reader(oDs1))` and now you can do `header = rDs1[0]` and `firstRow = rDs1[1]`.

Comment: I know that using what's to me is cumbersome `rDs1 = list(reader(oDs1))` does work as would something like this `listDs1 = list(rDs1)` and then `header = listDs1[0]` and then anything else but I see you understand I would like to do most of the job on a single line. Then it seems you are right, any explanation on what's a generator or a link to it? EDIT: Reading back what I wrote I sounded very "rude", thank you for pointing me out what's I was totally missing

Comment: Generators: https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Also, avoid the desire to do things in one line. It just makes code harder to rest and harder to debug.

You should be doing this all in pandas anyway so if I were you I wouldn't focus too hard on any of this.